# kableExtra rmarkdown tables - aligning grouping row labels and footnotes

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am using `kableExtra` to format some tables in an Rmarkdown document. When running the code below, without any `position` argument to `kable_styling`, the grouping row labels (the rows in the table where it says "Group 1" and "Group 2") and the footnotes remain left aligned in relation to the table. This is as I would like it.

````
```{r cars-table, results='asis'}
kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:2], format = "html", caption = "Group Rows", 
     col.names = c("MPG[note]", "CYL[note]")) %>%
kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
group_rows("Group 1", 4, 7) %>%
group_rows("Group 2", 8, 10) %>% 
add_footnote(c("Some footnote", "Some other footnote"))
```
````

[image: kableExtra_workingtable]

But when a `position` argument is provided to `kable_styling`, the grouping row labels and footnotes seem to take the opposite alignment, rather than remaining left aligned in relation to the table. I say the opposite alignment, as when I use `position = "right"`, the grouping row labels and footnotes become left aligned.

The code below demonstrates the issue when using `position = "left"`.

````
```{r cars-table, results='asis'}
kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:2], format = "html", caption = "Group Rows", 
     col.names = c("MPG[note]", "CYL[note]")) %>%
kable_styling("striped", full_width = F, position = "left") %>%
group_rows("Group 1", 4, 7) %>%
group_rows("Group 2", 8, 10) %>% 
add_footnote(c("Some footnote", "Some other footnote"))
```
````

[image: kableExtra_notworkingtable]

I only load two libraries to make this example and use the defaults when opening an .Rmd document in RStudio.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

What can I do to make the grouping row labels and footnotes left aligned in relation to the table? Thanks.

Comment: Ops.... I found that when you selected `left`, the corresponding CSS code is `left = "text-align: right;`.... I will make a fix very soon......

Comment: Fixed now. Please install from github.

Comment: @Hao Wonderful, thanks very much! Love the kableExtra package, thanks for your work on it!

Comment: @Hao Do you want to put some sort of answer in so I can accept and close the question?

Comment: @meenparam Haha, sure. :)

Comment: @Hao Thanks! Just wanted to avoid people seeing it as an unanswered question and trying to help out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `kableExtra` 0.3.0 or earlier, there was a bug in the `position` section of `kable_styling`. The corresponding CSS for `left` positioning was mistakenly set as `text-align:right`... Thank you, @meenaparam, for bringing it up!

Now this bug has been addressed in the current dev version and the CRAN version will be updated in a week.

Comment: I just checked the dev version and the alignment works! However, the footnotes have disappeared. The superscript tiny numbers are still present in the table, but the actual footnote text has gone. Any ideas?